# Angular v13 Jest with nx test - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module at Runtime.createScriptFromCode

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, nomachine-nx

I tried to follow every comment with a possible solution [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7844) to the letter. I relied on an example project on github as well which works perfectly.

This also started to happen to me after updating everything manually and when running the nx test command, occurrs this error.

My jest.config.js inside **apps/my-app:**

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: "../../jest.preset.js",
    coverageDirectory: "../../coverage/apps/my-app",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "html", "js", "json", "mjs"],
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
    resolver: "jest-preset-angular/build/resolvers/ng-jest-resolver.js",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts"],
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
            stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.(html|svg)$",
            useESM: true
        }
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$": "jest-preset-angular",
    },
    displayName: "my-app",
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes",
        "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot",
        "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment",
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)",
        "node_modules/(?!lodash-es)",
        "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|@ionic-native|@ionic)"
    ]
};
```

**jest.config.js** in the project root:

```js
const { getJestProjects } = require("@nrwl/jest");

module.exports = { projects: getJestProjects() };
```

**jest.preset.js** in the root project:

```js
const nxPreset = require("@nrwl/jest/preset");
module.exports = {
    ...nxPreset,
    testMatch: ["**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "ts-jest",
    },
    resolver: "@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "html"],
    coverageReporters: ["html"],
};
```

**package.json:**

```js
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.1.10",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      ...
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1301.2",
        "@angular/animations": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "13.1.0",
        "@awesome-cordova-plugins/device": "5.37.2",
        "@ionic-enterprise/cordova": "9.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/clipboard": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "5.36.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "6.0.0",
        "@ionic/storage-angular": "3.0.6",
        "@ng-idle/core": "11.1.0",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "11.0.3",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
        "@sentry/angular": "6.16.1",
        "@sentry/tracing": "6.16.1",
        "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "6.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.5",
        "core-js": "3.19.3",
        "crypto-es": "1.2.7",
        "document-register-element": "1.14.10",
        "dom-to-image": "2.6.0",
        "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
        "moment": "2.29.1",
        "native-run": "1.5.0",
        "ng-circle-progress": "1.6.0",
        "node-forge": "0.10.0",
        "npm": "8.3.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "7.4.0",
        "sass": "1.45.0",
        "tslib": "2.3.1",
        "uuid": "8.3.2",
        "zone.js": "0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-architects/ddd": "1.5.1",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.0.1",
        "@angular/cli": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "13.1.0",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "3.0.0",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic/cli": "6.18.1",
        "@nrwl/angular": "13.3.2",
        "@nrwl/cli": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/cypress": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/jest": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/linter": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/node": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/workspace": "13.3.1",
        "@schematics/angular": "13.1.0",
        "@types/dom-to-image": "2.6.4",
        "@types/jest": "27.0.3",
        "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.5",
        "@types/node": "16.11.12",
        "@types/node-forge": "0.10.10",
        "@types/uuid": "8.3.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.1",
        "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
        "compare-func": "2.0.0",
        "cordova": "10.0.0",
        "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
        "cordova-clipboard": "1.3.0",
        "cordova-ios": "6.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx": "3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "1.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.12",
        "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-iroot": " 3.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-proguard": "2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo": " 5.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "6.0.3",
        "cordova-res": "0.15.4",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "6.0.0",
        "cordova-unique-device-id": "1.3.2",
        "cypress": "8.7.0",
        "dotenv": "10.0.0",
        "dtslint": "4.2.1",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
        "eslint": "8.4.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.12.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
        "fuzzy": "0.1.3",
        "inquirer": "8.2.0",
        "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "1.4.0",
        "jest": "27.4.5",
        "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.1",
        "ncu": "0.2.1",
        "ng-packagr": "13.1.0",
        "ngx-unused-css": "3.0.0",
        "npm-check-updates": "12.0.3",
        "npx": "10.2.2",
        "open": "8.4.0",
        "prettier": "2.5.1",
        "stylelint": "14.1.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "24.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
        "ts-node": "9.1.1",
        "typescript": "^4.4.4",
        "webpack": "5.30.0",
        "xml2js": "0.4.23"
    },
    "description": "An ionic project",
    "browser": {
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "La aplicación requiere acceso a la biblioteca de fotos para funcionar apropiadamente.",
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "La aplicación requiere acceso a la biblioteca de fotos para funcionar apropiadamente."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
            "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
            "cordova-plugin-proguard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-unique-device-id": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": {
                "FACEID_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo": {},
            "cordova-plugin-iroot": {},
            "cordova-clipboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "ios",
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

I still keep getting this error: :/

```js
    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Repos\temp-repos\my-app\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2015\testing.mjs:7
    import { getDebugNode, RendererFactory2, ɵstringify, ɵReflectionCapabilities, Directive, Component, Pipe, NgModule, ɵgetInjectableDef, resolveForwardRef, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ApplicationInitStatus, LOCALE_ID, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵcompileComponent, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵcompileDirective, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵcompilePipe, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, NgZone, Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, ɵNgModuleFactory, ModuleWithComponentFactories, InjectionToken, Injector, InjectFlags, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible } from '@angular/core';       
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
```

Thansk for your replies.

Comment: have you tried not updating everything manually, by using the command `nx migrate latest` ?  (https://nx.dev/l/r/core-concepts/updating-nx) there are many little upgrades you have to make in ng's and nx's configs

Comment: There's an error in the migration. I had the same issue 3 days ago. The `transform` field is missing `|mjs`. The `jest.config.js` you posted looks fine, but you most likely have another library/application in your workspace with a **jest.config.js** where `|mjs` is still missing

Comment: @TheFabio Yes, I did the migration with that command nx migrate latest and then the installation. I run nx reset (which usually clears coverage and cache) and then nx test, the error continues in the app.component.spec.ts. Pieterjan Which of the files specifically is missing? preset? Because at the moment I'm only scanning a project, the rest is on lib (mono-repo), it only goes through app.component.spec.ts and I don't know what module it is still including.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From what I've found online, this seems like a common issue to projects using Jest and upgrading to Angular 13. Our project doesn't use `nx` but here are the updates to our Jest config:

```js
// jest.config.js
const esModules = ['@angular', '@ngrx', 'd3', [...] ];

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true,
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|${esModules.join('|')})`,
  ]
};
```

What solved my problem was [this comment](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1149#issuecomment-963506942) on a closed issue (jest-preset-angular). Ignoring the modules, in my case `@angular` and `@ngrx`, solved the error posted in your question. Specifically this line:

```js
const esModules = ['@angular', '@ngrx', 'd3', [...] ];
```

---

Update: The transform ignore patterns merged into a single pattern for node_module files and modules to solve a different issue.

Comment: Although I didn't get to test it this way and put the reply fix this error, what I did was go back to Angular v12 and everything worked as before with nx. See how I ended up answering on the matter here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7844#issuecomment-1004930232 Thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer fixed it for me. I made a [script](https://gist.github.com/ajsaraujo/c1ff492be98f8f7fa01372ca4b2bb18b) to apply the changes to all the jest.config.js files automatically

Comment: Works fine. Thanks! Eventually you have to add `mjs` to `transform` and ignore `node_modules`

Comment: This was the only thing that helped fix an issue migrating to Angular 13. Only problem is it has made the tests considerably slower. For now I'll take slow tests over inexplicably broken tests =)